# How to set a class instance to userdefaults in swift?

Tags: iphone, ios7, swift

I researched it, but I couldnt find the right solution. I want to set a class instance to userDefaults. Assume that I have a class like this:

```
class Person {    
  var id: Int    
  var name: String    
  var email: String

   init() {
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.email = ""   
   } 
}
```

I created an instance from person class, after WebService call finished and I did:

```
   var person: Person = Person()
   person.id    = personJSON.valueForKey(WSConstants.USER_ID) as Int
   person.name  = personJSON.valueForKey(WSConstants.USER_NAME) as String
   person.email = personJSON.valueForKey(WSConstants.USER_EMAIL) as String
```

and then, I actually want to do this:

```
   var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   userDefaults.setObject(person, forKey: "personInfo")
   userDefaults.synchronize()
```

but I it is wrong, what is the right way to set a class instance to userDefaults ?

Thanks for your answers,

Best regards

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not a general purpose database/persistence store. For saving state there are good options such as `NSArchiver` and Core Data among others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [**NSUserDefaults Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:):

> The `value` parameter can be only property list objects: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. For `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, their contents must be property list objects.

You need to serialize your `Person` instance into one of those objects before saving it into the user defaults.

One of many ways to do it is to implement `NSCoding` protocol in your class:

```
class Person: NSCoding {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("id")
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeStringForKey("name")
        self.email = aDecoder.decodeStringForKey("email")
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(self.id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encodeString(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeString(self.email, forKey: "email")
    }

}

// when writing your defaults...

let personData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(person)
userDefaults.setObject(personData, forKey: "personInfo")

// then, when reading your defaults...

let personData = userDefaults.objectForKey("personInfo") as NSData?

if let personData = personData? {
    let person = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(personData) as Person
}
```

Alternatively, you can just save your `personJSON` dictionary to the defaults.

Comment: Well, In another class, I am going to use another userDefaults. But in that class another class instance exists. Assume that, in class "A", the class B instance exists. How can I make serializable class B in class A ?

Comment: Just use `encodeObject(nestedObject, forKey: "key")`

Comment: Just make sure it conforms to `NSCoding` too. ;)